# Autofilter on a currentregion resized

Tags: excel, vba, range, autofilter

I am trying to optimize the update processing time of Excel file from an Access application so I want to apply autofilter on a resized currentRegion.

This code below is a part of a Access routine which add / update an Excel file with a Access recordset data.

```
     With xlsWkSheet
         .AutoFilterMode = True

         lXlsRowNumber = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range("ColRef").Column).End(xlUp).Row
         Set oXlsCurrentRegion=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(RowSize:=lXlsRowNumber)

         With oXlsCurrentRegion
            .AutoFilterMode = True

            lIdxCol = .Range("ColCrit1").Column
            .AutoFilter Field:=lIdxCol, Criteria1:=IIf(Nz(oRecSet![ValueAccess], "") = "", "=", oRecSet![ValueAccess]) 
            End If

            Set xlsRangeAutoFilter = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        End With
```

When "=" is applied on autofilter because oRecSet![ValueAccess] is null, on left top corner of Excel file, it's displayed

> 0 Of 1047585 records found.

When I apply autofilter on blank file with only headers I expected « 0 of 1 records founds »

I hoped that the filter was only applied on oXlsCurrentRegion areas but apparently not!

Is there a way to apply blank criteria only on XlsCurrentRegion areas?

Comment: First things first, check `oXlsCurrentRegion` with `MsgBox oXlsCurrentRegion.Address`

Comment: And maybe the first `AutoFilterMode` should be `False`

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help. I have to wait next Monday for checking  address and changing for False. I make a feedback as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Chris, you're right about autofilterMode. Its value must  be False! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

On [The Ultimate Guide to Excel Filters with VBA Macros – AutoFilter Method](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macros-filters-autofilter-method/) we can read this code below which seems to be the solution of my problem

```
Sub AutoFilter_Range()
'AutoFilter is a member of the Range object

'Reference the entire range that the filters are applied to
'AutoFilter turns filters on/off when no parameters are specified.
Sheet1.Range("B3:G1000").AutoFilter

'Fully qualified reference starting at Workbook level
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AutoFilter Guide").Range("B3:G1000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

And as we can read on [How to use AutoFilters in Excel VBA Macros](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba.htm)

AutoFilterMode and FilterMode  must be set with False value

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code on a Excel file and it works perfectly

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   With ActiveSheet
     .FilterMode = False
     .AutoFilterMode = False

      Set oRange = .Range("A2:E8")
      With oRange
       .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
      End With    
   End With
End Sub
```

[image: 6 rows found of 6 (6 enreg. trouvé(s) sur 6)]